# What is Master Device in MIDI?

Tags: mac, midi

So, what is the "Master Device" in Multi-output device? Cause I'm trying figure out how MIDI Aggregate Devices work, I need to now what is it.

Answer (score 2):

MIDI system needs to know who is the master.

It is for the master volume adjustment when you have **multiple output devices**.

Each output device can have its own volume adjustment preset, but the master volume will control overall Volume.

The MIDI has 2 options to set up:

[image: MIDI]

The Create Multi-Output is self explanatory.

The Aggregate is:

> You can combine several audio devices to use as a single device, known
>   as an “aggregate device.” By aggregating devices, you can increase the
>   number of discrete audio inputs and outputs without purchasing more
>   expensive multichanneled audio equipment. For example, if you have an
>   eight-channel audio device and a two-channel audio device, you can
>   combine them to work as a single ten-channel audio device.
>
> For the aggregate device to work correctly, the sample rates of the
>   combined devices in the aggregate device must be set to the same
>   sample rate.